# How can I put two values from mysql table into one variable?

Tags: mysql, select, pdo

This is how my query looks like:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *,
s.name as name,
s.firstname as firstname,
FROM projects pj
LEFT JOIN school s ON pj.teacher=s.id 
WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  
$pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["firstname"].' '.$row["name"];
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to put two values into one variable. I imagine something like this:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *,
s.firstname.''.name as teacher,
FROM projects pj
LEFT JOIN school s ON pj.teacher=s.id 
WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  
$pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["teacher"];
}
```

Comment: You can use concat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mysql, you can `concat` to concatenate:

```
SELECT *,
CONCAT(s.firstname, s.name) as teacher,
FROM projects pj
LEFT JOIN school s ON pj.teacher=s.id 
WHERE project_id = :project_id
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-concat-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: This will output `firstnamename` as teacher column you forgot to include a space.

Comment: If you look at the original question, there is no space, thus I'm doing the same thing `s.firstname.''.name as teacher`

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's CONCAT:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *,
CONCAT(s.firstname, ' ', s.name) AS teacher
FROM projects pj
LEFT JOIN school s ON pj.teacher=s.id 
WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  

$pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["teacher"];
}
```